Alt +esc doesn't change focus when an app is set "Always on Top"
After I put Gnome Clock to always on top by Alt+Space,then whenever I did Alt+Esc , it changed the blue box from window to window but does not brought anyone of them to focus.
For example, I opened Firefox through the shortcut, It brought it on second top(after clock) position but didn't change the focus till I deliberately click somewhere in the browser from mouse to bring it back to focus.
Is this a normal behavior of Ubuntu, and if so how can I change it so that the shortcut would also change the focus to the window and not only bring it on the top.

This is indeed a bug related to the window manager Mutter in Ubuntu 22.04 which likely is resolved in later editions. I can reproduce the issue in Ubuntu 22.04 (based on Gnome 42). I cannot reproduce this in Fedora 40 (based on Gnome 45).
It is strange how such a rather serious bug, breaking the "Always on top"  feature, persisted throughout in a long term release. However, at this time, 2024-04-12, the new LTS is around the corner, so you will soon be able to upgrade to another LTS.

hey @vanadium , the first extension is unsupported and the other 2 are not having the effect even after being installed, I have gnome version 42.9.

Thanks for your feedback. My apologies, I did not test on Ubuntu earlier. Yes, you are right, this is broken on Ubuntu 22.04. I remember that that version took a version of mutter that was quite strongly updated, introducing a lot of bugs. This is probably one of the symptoms. I had to change my answer, of course.

I think that I should then report it as a bug to ubuntu.
